# Xamarin.Forms How to save model to database without savebutton, Best practises

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My colleague and I want to create an application with some pages, where the user is allowed to change some settings. These settingspages do not have savebuttons. There is a main settingspage and two child settingspages. The settings should be persisted if the user navigates back from one of the three pages or the user makes some changes in one of the child pages.
The model is loaded in the OnAppearing() Method of the main settingspage. So we can not use OnDisappearing() Method of the childpages to save the model, because the sequence of these methods and Pushed() and Popped() of the navigationpage differs on each platform: forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21417/navigationpage-push-pop-event-sequence-different-across-platforms

Our solution at this time is to save the model in the setters of the properties of the childpages viewmodels. But that could not be best practise. So our question is: Are there any other solutions to solve this problem? What are the best practises for that problem?

Code:

```cs
public ReminderRepetitive ListViewSelectedItem
    {
        get { return _settingsEntity.ReminderRepetitive; }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_settingsEntity.ReminderRepetitive, value))
            {
                _settingsEntity.ReminderRepetitive = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListViewSelectedItem");
                Save();
                _navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        }
    }


public void Save()
    {
        _businessLayer.UpdateSettings(_settingsEntity);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are improvements to be made with your code.

You shouldn't do the navigation from a property - if you're going to be navigating away at least make that a method. That method should be `async` and you should `await` for the `_navigation.PopAsync()`

Even calling the Save() shouldn't be there. Consider what happens if an exception occurs while saving: duplicate keys, null fields etc are all possible. Then not only you won't `Save` but you won't `PopAsync` either and your `ListViewSelectedItem = newItem` will cause your selected item handler to blow up as well. And if you're going to have a property that also handles showing error messages you're definitely well inside MessyCode territory.

You can use the PropertyChanged on your model (ReminderRepetitive) and save immediately as soon as a property is changed.

It looks like you have a `_businessLayer` the whole business of saving or updating may belong there.

As a whole your question is pretty broad and can be treated as "opinion based". Next time try asking about specific parts of the code you're not sure about or cause errors - or use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)